# Hide textbox which contains a hardcoded text on the basis of any dataset value in RDLC

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, rdlc

In my report I have a textbox following a table. the table needs to be hide on some condition with above textbox (containing hard-coded label for this). i have set the visibility for tablix and its get hide. but how to hide the label because no dataset is connected to the label.

Comment: What is the expression you are using to hide the table?

Comment: Set the visibility of the textbox based on the tablix dataset.